# Is my Ray-Triangle Intersection code correct?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, intersection

I'm asking here if anyone can check if my Ray-Triangle intersection code is correct or do I have some mistake in it since it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Vector3f:

```
struct Vector3f
{
    Vector3f(): x(0), y(0), z(0) { }
    Vector3f(GLfloat a, GLfloat b, GLfloat c): x(a), y(b), z(c) { }

    GLfloat x, y, z;
};
```

CrossProduct & InnerProduct:

```
Vector3f CMath::CrossProduct(Vector3f a, Vector3f b)
{
    Vector3f result;

    result.x = (a.y * b.z) - (a.z * b.y);
    result.y = (a.z * b.x) - (a.x * b.z);
    result.z = (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x);

    return result;
}
GLfloat CMath::InnerProduct(Vector3f a, Vector3f b)
{
    return (a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y) + (a.z * b.z);
}
```

Ray-Triangle Intersection Check:

```
bool CMath::RayIntersectsTriangle(Vector3f p, Vector3f d, Vector3f v0, Vector3f v1, Vector3f v2, Vector3f &hitLocation)
{
    Vector3f e1, e2, h, s, q;
    GLfloat a, f, u, v, t;

    e1.x = v1.x - v0.x;
    e1.y = v1.y - v0.y;
    e1.z = v1.z - v0.z;

    e2.x = v2.x - v0.x;
    e2.y = v2.y - v0.y;
    e2.z = v2.z - v0.z;

    h = CrossProduct(d,e2);
    a = InnerProduct(e1,h);
    if(a > -0.00001 && a < 0.00001)
        return false;

    f = 1 / a;
    s.x = p.x - v0.x;
    s.y = p.y - v0.y;
    s.z = p.z - v0.z;
    u = f * InnerProduct(s,h);
    if(u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        return false;

    q = CrossProduct(s,e1);
    v = f * InnerProduct(d,q);
    if(v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0)
        return false;

    t = f * InnerProduct(e2,d);
    if(t > 0.00001)
    {
        hitLocation.x = p.x + t * d.x;
        hitLocation.y = p.y + t * d.y;
        hitLocation.z = p.z + t * d.z;

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Just checking if there's anything wrong with these functions to know if my problem lies somewhere else.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I have tried but I think the problem is either with these functions or my code. Thanks for the comment though, gonna try this with a blank project to make it sure. I've used these same functions before and they worked fine, but can't remember if I changed them back in the day, about 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend to rename `InnerProduct` to `DotProduct` (See [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)).

You have a plane defined by 3 points `v0`, `v1` and `v2` and a ray defined by a point `p` and a direction `d`.
In pseudo code, the intersection point of the plan and the ray is:

```non
n = cross(v1-v0, v2-v0)        // normal vector of the plane
t = dot(v0 - p, n) / dot(d, n) // t scale d to the distance along d between p and the plane 
hitLocation = p + d * t
```

See also [Intersect a ray with a triangle in GLSL C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257678/intersect-a-ray-with-a-triangle-in-glsl-c/59261241#59261241)

When you apply that to your code that means

```cpp
Vector3f n = CrossProduct(e1, e2);
```

Note, since `s` is `p - v0` (rather than `v0 - p`), the scale for the ray direction has to be inverted:

```cpp
t = - InnerProduct(s, n) / InnerProduct(d, n)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea GLSL had those functions built-in. Haven't got into shaders yet really. I'll look into GLSL more, thanks also for the explanations