# Dot prodoct limit to triangle edges

Tags: math, glsl, webgl

I want to limit the dot product to the edges of the triangle. To find its Ray Triangle intersection with the triangle using normals.
Language: GLSL

[image]

[image]
Edit:

```
//? for unknown number
vect3 normal = vec3(?,?,?);
vect3 rayDir = vec3(?,?,?);

float dotProduct = dot(normal,rayDir), 0.0);

if (dotProduct == 1.0){//complete face to face
  return true;
}

if (dotProduct >= ???){how many less than correct ?limit to the edge.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show something which makes this a StackOverlfow question rather than a question for the Blender sibling https://blender.stackexchange.com Maybe something about input, output and the code you have attempted to write for in between. Compare [ask].

Comment: "I want to limit the dot product to the edges of the triangle." What is your code for calculating the unlimited dot product?

Comment: The glsl dot product produces a value between -1 and 1, so if the value is 1 the intersection is correct but I want to find out how many numbers less than that will work.
This is not a Blender question but a GLSL shader and math question.

Comment: *"The glsl dot product produces a value between -1 and 1,"* - no that is wrong. The result of the dot product depends on the length of the vectors. Only if the vectors are normalized, the result is between -1 and 1. See [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Comment: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution
Basically what you do is intersect with the plane, then check if the point on the plane lies within the triangle by dotting it onto the tangent(=vector perpendicular to the edge direction) of each of the edges and checking if  it's on the right side.

Comment: No idea what this question is about. If you want to intersect a ray and a tringle, see: [Intersect a ray with a triangle in GLSL C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257678/intersect-a-ray-with-a-triangle-in-glsl-c/59261241#59261241).